# Host onion site at home

Tags: onion-services

I want to create a blog on onion, there will be nothing illegal, just tutorials on linux, programming and other related topics. What are the risks? Is it safer to pay for a VPS in another country?

Comment: What does "safe" mean in this context? To stay anonymous? Or do you mean to protect your website from malicious people (hacking, denial of service, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

As for technical aspect it is quite easy. E.g. try this https://onionshare.org/
This will even create a domain for you.

The risks depend on your jurisdiction. If you are in Northern Korea you will be charged even for this question. Otherwise there is no risk if you do not share illegal stuff. The disadvantage of home site is that your PC must be always on. But you can find some affordable VPS for up to $5/mo. (You need VPS with root access to setup and run tor). 
If you need however some anonymity you will need a hosting provider who accepts Bitcoins because other payment methods will leak your identities. Then you need to install tor on your local PC to safely connect to VPS. And please google for "how to run onion site and stay out of jail" as there are many things you must take into account to keep yourself anonymous.